# How to download a url image to an existing list view

Tags: java, android, url, imageview

i have a custom listview with its own base adapter. it has a title and discription at the moment. id like to add an image from a url. but i dont know how to adjust the code to add add said image.

im already using an async task to download a file when the item in the listview is pressed could i reuse this method to add the images?

my async task for file downloading only at moment

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream to write file
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Download/"+newnamestring);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task
     * Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded

        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + newnamestring)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);




    }

}
```

my custom base adapter

```
class dataListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String[] Title, Detail;


    dataListAdapter() {
        Title = null;
        Detail = null;

        ;

    }

    public dataListAdapter(String[] text, String[] text1 ) {
        Title = text;
        Detail = text1;





    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Title.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row;

        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);
        TextView title, detail;
        title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.titleapp);
        detail = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.detail);
        title.setText(Title[position]);
        detail.setText(Detail[position]);
        return (row);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to download image from URL and show that into your ImageView the best thing you could do is to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library, this library can download Image and show into your imageView and cache it to use another time,
and that's how you can use it after add to your project;
`Glide.with(mContext).load(imageUrl).into(yourImageView);`

Comment: #Hamid thanks think i may have the glide library forgot all about that cheers